# Detect incoming calls inside a service

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Inside a service I have:

```
// subscribe to incoming call notifications
registerReceiver(mIncomingCallReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"));
```

However onReceive never gets called:

```
// incoming call receiver
private BroadcastReceiver mIncomingCallReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
```

What's wrong here? I don't want to declare it through the manifest and additional class since it would require additional code to invoke corresponding method inside my service.

P.S. What I need to do is to stop the service player when an incoming call is registered.

Comment: Have you looked at this? I think this blog may help you. Sorry, if i am wrong ! http://bitgriff.blogspot.in/2013/01/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-phone.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your manifest misses

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```